# sub-domain routing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have just put a practice laravel app on my development server at app.mydomain.co

I have looked at the docs and I wrapped the routes with the sub domain group like so

```
 <?php

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
    | It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
    | and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
    |
    */
    Route::group(array('domain' => 'app.mydomain.co'), function()
    {
    Route::get('/', array('as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'QuestionController@getIndex'));
    //Route::get('create', array('as'=>'create', 'uses'=>'UserController@getCreate'));
    //Route::get('login', array('as'=>'login', 'uses'=>'UserController@getLogin'));

    /*
        Define RESTful Controllers
    */
        Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
        Route::controller('questions', 'QuestionController');
    });
```

The home page works fine but the rest of the routes are 404 not found errors so obviously I am doing something wrong, any ideas?

here is the output for php artisan routes with the domain substituted with app

```
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain       | URI                                                    | Name | Action                              | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| qapp.app.co | GET /user/index/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}               |      | UserController@getIndex             |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /user                                              |      | UserController@getIndex             |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /user/create/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}              |      | UserController@getCreate            |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | POST /user/store/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}              |      | UserController@postStore            |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /user/login/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}               |      | UserController@getLogin             |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | POST /user/login/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}              |      | UserController@postLogin            |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /user/logout/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}              |      | UserController@getLogout            |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /user/{_missing}                                   |      | UserController@missingMethod        |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /questions/index/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}          |      | QuestionController@getIndex         |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /questions                                         |      | QuestionController@getIndex         |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | POST /questions/store/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}         |      | QuestionController@postStore        |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /questions/show/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}           |      | QuestionController@getShow          |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /questions/edit/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}           |      | QuestionController@getEdit          |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | PUT /questions/update/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}         |      | QuestionController@putUpdate        |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /questions/your-questions/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5} |      | QuestionController@getYourQuestions |                |               |
| qapp.app.co | GET /questions/{_missing}                              |      | QuestionController@missingMethod    |                |               |
|              | GET /                                                  | home | QuestionController@getIndex
```

When I look at the apache error log it appears to be looking in the laravel public folder for  a file or directory related to the php query so if I am trying to access the questions controller method show with url qapp.app.co/questions/show/14 the error is file does not exist: /var/www/app/public/questions

Comment: You didn't define any parameter in your route to store the subdomain  so I don't see the point of using Sub-domain Routes at all.

Sub-domain routes are meant to be used to so somethng with the subdomian. Example:

    Route::group(array('domain' => '{language}.mydomain.co'), function() {

        //May be change global lang here ...
        //App::setLocale($language);

        //.. or just pass it to the routes/controllers
        Route::get('user/{id}', function($language, $id) {
            /* ... */
        });

    });

Comment: I just want to be able to use the app as normal from app.mydomain.co

Comment: @Ir1sh Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @aaronjbaptiste no havn't found the problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by setting AllowOverride to All in the virtual host. Maybe it will work for you too? See http://laracasts.com/forum/351-how-do-you-install-laravel-into-a-subdomain

Answer (score 0):

> The home page works fine but the rest of the routes are not found errors so obviously I am doing something wrong

This would already give you a hint what's actually wrong with your config. The route would prioritize from top to bottom, so technically you should define '/' route at the bottom (and not the top.

Comment: Thanks but moving the definition of the home route has made no difference I still get a 404 error